# Angular PWA - SwUpdate 'available' not being triggered

Tags: angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

I have an Update Service injected into app.component.ts that should subscribe to the 'available' subscription. However, after multiple deployments to our staging environment, I am unable to reach the console.log within.  When starting the app, I see the initial console.logs for `logUpdate()` and `checkForUpdate()`. The `checkForUpdate()` is being triggered as I can see the browser fetching every 10 seconds. However, after making a change to the application and pushing up to our environment and waiting 10 seconds, the code within the `available` subscribe does not get triggered... Am I implementing this correctly?

Here is the service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ServiceWorkerService {

  constructor(private appRef: ApplicationRef,
          private updates: SwUpdate,
          private snackbar: MatSnackBar) {
    // log and check for updates
  }

  logUpdate() {
    console.log('logUpdate()');
    this.updates.available.subscribe(evt => {
      console.log('Update Available: ', evt);
      const snack = this.snackbar.open('Update Available', 'Reload', {
        duration: 6000
      });

      snack
        .onAction()
        .subscribe(() => {
          window.location.reload();
        });
    });
    this.updates.activated.subscribe(event => {
      console.log('old version was', event.previous);
      console.log('new version is', event.current);
    });
  }

  checkForUpdate() {
    console.log('checkForUpdate()');
    // Allow the app to stabilize first, before starting polling for updates with `interval()`.
    const appIsStable$ = this.appRef.isStable.pipe(first(isStable => isStable === true));
    // const everySixHours$ = interval(6 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    const everySixHours$ = interval(10 * 1000);
    const everySixHoursOnceAppIsStable$ = concat(appIsStable$, everySixHours$);

    everySixHoursOnceAppIsStable$.subscribe(() => this.updates.checkForUpdate());
  }
}
```

the ngsw-config.json:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/manifest.webmanifest",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.scss",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and the app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  environment = environment;

  constructor(private swService: ServiceWorkerService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.swService.logUpdate();
    this.swService.checkForUpdate();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar code and missing `SwUpdate.available` event as well. It detected changes reliably on `localhost` (when running with http-server) but not on DEV deployment.

In my case, service-worker was running in degraded mode. You can check this by accessing `ngws/state` URL (relative to your application) as described in the angular documentation:

https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-devops#debugging-the-angular-service-worker

The cause for degraded mode was feature-toggle file: It was present with some defaults under `/assets/` for local environment and was overwritten for each stage during deployment. This resulted in content-hash mismatch for the file.

Excluding the file within ngsw-config.json solved the problem.